# System.Drawing.Common throws DllNotFoundException in Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, .net-5, system.drawing.common

I am using `System.Drawing.Common` in my code, but when I deploy it to Linux Container (Ubuntu 20.04, Focal Fossa) it shows me there's an error, that `user32.dll` was not found, which is a Windows application. 
 Here's an image of the error ~ [image]

Comment: Does this help: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-do-you-use-systemdrawing-in-net-core ?

Comment: No, it merely demonstrates the library. I have a very specific error, as you can see

Comment: It does say to install a couple of packages, `libc6-dev` and `libgdiplus`.  Have you done that?

Comment: Yes. Besides, the error is about a library `user32` not `libc6-dev` or `libgdiplus`